# How do I create tabs for an iPhone app without using the Tab Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am teaching myself iOS5 with Xcode 4.2.1 and did a bit of digging into tabs.  I found information on tab bars and how to make them do a lot of neat things, however, I have not found any information on how to create this type of tab:

[image]

I came to the conclusion that this type of tab cannot be created using a Tab Bar app or utilizing the toolbar in some fancy way, based on the research I have done. How can I create this type of tab for an iPhone app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple customized 'UIButton' objects, or a customized 'UISegmentedControl', that when tapped change the contents of 'UIView' which gives you the desired effect.

Comment: After some more searching I have come up empty on how I would go about this.  Do you know of a link that could help me get started?